# subprocess.Popen or proc.stdout.read() corrupting JSON data

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am running a PHP script through Python Django as it contains legacy code for a client.

Data is passed to through to the PHP script via JSON and after the script is computed a string is returned for display like so.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["php -f script.php " + json.dumps(data_for_php, sort_keys=True)], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
script_response = proc.stdout.read()
return HttpResponse(script_response)
```

The issue I am having is something in this process is corrupting the data.

i.e. one JSON field from `data_for_php` has the key and value `'xxx_amount': u'$350,000.00',` returns `,000.00,` as the value in `script_response`.

It's not doing this for anything else.

I have been doing a bit of debugging and have determined that `json.dumps(data_for_php, sort_keys=True)` is not causing the issue, also `data_for_php` is good too.

It leads me to believe that this command `proc.stdout.read()` is some how mutating `$350` to  (space).

Note: same thing is occurring for other dictionary values.

**Update**

I have been lead to believe that the process I am using is a command line script inside Python. When the command is called the JSON variables are being passed inside the command line script. This is probably the issue. Looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$350` in bash is a variable, in the shell it gets replaced by its value, which is not defined. Adding a single quote aroud the the dump should do the trick to avoir interpreting special characters:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["php -f script.php '" + json.dumps(data_for_php, sort_keys=True) + "'"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
script_response = proc.stdout.read()
return HttpResponse(script_response)
```

Comment: I didn't think about it before, but if there are any single quote in your JSON data this trick will fail. You'd have to escape it first with something like: `json.dumps(data_for_php, sort_keys=True).replace("'", r"\'")`